# Bind function to custom condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

Note: I rarely use JS and jQuery so please excuse if the question is odd.

I am trying to add a div to my page (to a menu specifically) but only if the page is smaller than a certain width. Basically I need an event handler that allows me to wait for that condition to be met and run a function once it is (similar to how you would do with on.("click")) but I have no idea how to accomplish that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the following code:

```
var $myDiv = $("<div class='myDiv'></div>");
$(window).resize(function () {
    var windowWidth = $(this).width();
    if (windowWidth < 200) {
        $("body").append($myDiv);
    } else {
        $myDiv.remove();
    }
});
```

we monitor the window resize event, and append/remove the div as per your condition.

<kbd>[**Live Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/4wmoLn98/)</kbd>

play around with the bottom right side of the fiddle (the result pane) and resize it to see what happens.

Answer (score -2):

This is without the event handler, but you can add it in a resize event handler:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width:700px)").matches) {
 // viewport width is at least 700px
 } else {
 // viewport is smaller than 700px 
 }
```